# get table id in migration file (laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-5.8

I want id of the users. (in migrations to use the id in if statements and add different default values to new table column)

I tried to use `getColumns()->id` but it showing some warning in ide(Field id not found).

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddUserRoles extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $ID = $table->getColumns()->id;


           if($ID == '1') {
               $table->string('role')->default('admin');
               } else {
                 $table->string('role')->default('member');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table...
              .....
    }
}
```

EDIT: this the users table

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my purpose is to use id for setting different default roles to the users table.

Comment: How do you plan to read users id if you don't even have the users table in your database?

Comment: I have created it. (i will edit the question)

Comment: maybe I'm wrong in the first place!? I shouldn't create two migrations and i have to merge them. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read users while creating the users table, since you does not have any users yet.

Create this table for users:

```php
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('role')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Then, you can add users and check the `id` to assign them a role:

```php
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'name';
$user->email = 'email@example.com';
$user->password = Hash::make("123456");
$user->save();

if ($user->id === $someId) {
    $user->role = 'some_role';
    $user->save();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you are right. I should change the value in the controller, not in the migration file. thank you.

Comment: Glad that i can help you :)